# Select Distinct Records From Sql Server With Entity Framework Using Repository Pattern In .Net Core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern

I am using the repository pattern with the .Net Core Web Application that communicates with .Net Core Web API Controller Methods to get records from SqlServer.

On the Web API Controller method, I am calling a method in the repository which must return a list of distinct messages based on a specific field in the Sql Server database like PhoneNumberTo. However, there seem to be some casting errors when I am returning the list back to the API method. Here is my Web API Controller method which calls the repository:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUniqueMessages")]
    public IActionResult GetUniqueMessages()
    {
        var messages = _unitOfWork.MessagesViewModel.GetDistinctMessages();
        return new JsonResult(messages);
    }
```

And here is my repository method which must return the list of  distinct messages:

```
     public IEnumerable<Message> GetDistinctMessages()
     {    
            List<Message> result = _context.Messages.Select(m => m.PhoneNumberTo).Distinct().ToList();
            return result;
     }
```

Here is a screenshot of the error message I am getting on the repository method.

[image]

**Update:**

Here is my Message class:

[image]

Any expert suggestion will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two choices.

If you need to get a list of phone numbers only

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDistinctMessages()
{    
    return _context.Messages.Select(m => m.PhoneNumberTo).Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

If you need a list of messages, you can't have have all distinct fields, it will be the same like this

```
 public IEnumerable<Message> GetDistinctMessages()
 {    
       return _context.Messages.Distinct().ToArray();
 }
```

I offer you to get MessageTo MessageFrom and MessageText and see the difference

```
public IEnumerable<Message> GetDistinctMessages()
 {    
       return _context.Messages
                   .GroupBy(p => new {p.MessageTo, p.MessageFrom} )
                   .Select(g => new Message 
                     { 
                         MessageTo = g.Key.MessageTo, 
                         MessageFrom = g.Key.MessageFrom, 
                        MessageText= g.MessageText
                   }).ToArray();
```

You can play with this query and add as many fields as you need

you can still keep an existing action, but I recomend this

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUniqueMessages")]
    public IActionResult GetUniqueMessages()
    {
        var messages = _unitOfWork.MessagesViewModel.GetDistinctMessages();
        return Ok(messages);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I need a list of messages, not numbers. But this list must contain messages which are distinct based on phone numbers. Suppose a contact number has more than one message in my database table (send or received), I want to show that contact only once. Just like we see a list of contacts on web.whatsapp.com. When we click on a contact, the whole conversation history appears on the right side. I want to use this exact functionlaity.

Comment: The `_context.Messages.Distinct().ToArray();` still returns the whole list of messages from database.

Comment: If you need list of message  pls post message class

Comment: I have added my Message class. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Thank you. Can you  copy paste it instead of  the  image. Images are prohibited here.

Comment: Ohhhh... Sorry. Here it is:

public class Message : BaseEntity
    {
        public string MessageFrom { get; set; }
        public string MessageTo { get; set; }
        public string MessageText { get; set; }
        public bool IsRead { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @Noor Thanks , you could copy it in your question post using edit option. I updated my answer and try again. Let me know if you happy now.

Comment: Why I'm getting `there is no target type for 'new(string, string)'` error on `new ( p.MessageTo, p.MessageFrom)`?

Comment: @Noor Sorry It is hard to code without VS. I had some typo. I fixed them.  You can try again.

Comment: Ahhh... I guess the modified answer worked for me. I'll check the result by Monday and will be accepting this as an answer + a hit on the useful button. Thanks for your help.